# An Updated Salesforce's Picklist does'nt render a new value just added

Tags: picklist

I am new in Salesforce and I need to add a new value in a picklist. Once added, I save, but when a I need to create a new record of the object within which there is the picklist, the new value is not rendered. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add/enable this newly created picklist value in record type also.

Comment: Yes, I already did it. I correctly assigned the picklist value to the record type and enable it in the field dependencies. The thing is that one I create a new object the new value is not displayed in the picklist, while I try to update an existing object, it shows up. I do not understand why